# changing font color of equation and equation number in beamer presentation

Tags: color

I want to change the color of equation in a beamer presentation slide from the rest of text. I used following code, but the color of equation number is still black. How can change it.
MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}


    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{}
         The equation is given as 
        \begin{align}{\label{xn}
            \color{blue} x_{n}
            =\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum^{N-1}_{{k}=0}
            X_k e^{j2\pi kn/N},  \hspace{20mm} n=0,1, \dots,{N-1}}
        \end{align}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many of your previous questions have answers which seems to answer the questions. Why don't you go back and check which ones you can accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply move the instruction `\color{blue}` *outside* the display math environment. If there's material following the equation, encase both the `\color{blue}` instruction and the equation in a `\begingroup ... \endgroup` statement to limit the scope of the color-changing operation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}
The equation is given as 
\begingroup % localize scope of following instruction
\color{blue} % <-- new 
\begin{equation}\label{xn}
x_{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum^{N-1}_{k=0}
X_k e^{\,j2\pi kn/N} \qquad n=0,1,\dots,N-1
\end{equation}
\endgroup
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```